# Why am I getting an "Incorrect syntax near ')'" error for a CTE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm following Alex the Analyst's Portfolio Project for SQL Data Exploration - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfyynHBFOsM - (around the 59min mark) and I'm stuck on the "building a CTE" part:

```sql
WITH PopvsVac ( Continent, location, date, population, new_vaccinations, RollingPeopleVaccinated )
AS (
    SELECT
        dea.continent,
        dea.location,
        dea.date,
        dea.population,
        vac.new_vaccinations,
        SUM(CAST(vac.new_vaccinations AS bigint)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY dea.location
            ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
        ) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
    FROM
        PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths AS dea
        INNER JOIN PortfolioProject..CovidVaccinations AS vac ON 
            dea.location = vac.location
            AND
            dea.date = vac.date
    WHERE
        dea.continent IS NOT NULL
)
```

I understand that the original table has been updated since the video has been uploaded, which is why I've already made some adjustments to the query (bigint, ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), but I keep getting the

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How can I fix it so I can get the desired CTE as a result of the query?

Comment: THat can't be the whole statement. You define a CTE but don't use it.

Comment: Protip: you don't need to repeat the `Continent, location, date...` column names in the `WITH cteName ( Continent, location, date, ... )` line, you can have just `WITH PopvsVac AS  ( SELECT dea.continent, etc )`.

Comment: _"since the video has been uploaded"_ - what video? you haven't linked to the source or tutorial that you're using

Comment: `with` is a clause that is part of a larger statement (generally `select`), but you are missing the rest of that statement after the `with` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CTE. For example...

```
-- Note, you do not need to repeat the column names.
with PopvsVac as (
  ...
)
select *
from PopvsVac;
```